# how to change angularjs controller name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am just beginner in angularjs I want to change angularjs controller name according name is written with `templateUrl`.

Here is example

```
.when({ templateUrl:'template.html',controller:'mycontrollername'})
```

and now I want to send above controller name at bellow controller name.

```
app.controller('6th-septemberCtrl', ['$scope','$http','filterFilter', function ($scope,$http, filterFilter) {});
```

I have many controllers like this so want to send controller name according which route `templateUrl` is click imigiatily change the controller name and should worked as written like same default way

Answer (score 0):

I would create one static class which will hold the controller names per template.
Use the same class to get the names of the controller. Here is my example in code.

```
var app = angular.module("plunker", ["ngRoute"]);
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when("/", {
      templateUrl: "main.htm",
      controller: getControllerName('main.htm')
    })
    .when("/red", {
      templateUrl: "red.htm",
      controller: getControllerName('red.htm')
    })
    .when("/green", {
      templateUrl: "green.htm",
      controller: getControllerName('green.htm')
    });

});

function getControllerName(url) {
  for(var i=0; i<templateControllers.length; i++) {
    if(templateControllers[i].url === url)
      return templateControllers[i].controllerName;
  }
}

var templateControllers = [{
  url: 'main.htm',
  controllerName: 'mainController'
}, {
  url: 'red.htm',
  controllerName: 'redtroller'
}, {
  url: 'green.htm',
  controllerName: 'greenController'
}];

//create controller for main url
app.controller(getControllerName('main.htm'), function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'main';
});


//create controller for red url
app.controller(getControllerName('red.htm'), function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'red';
});



//create controller for green url
app.controller(getControllerName('green.htm'), function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'green';
});
```

Comment: thanks alot for your reply but i don't want to made different controller ,just want to make one controller and pass it names according routed page because have about 25 controller and changing only name and path in every controller so i thought it should b only one . is it good?

Comment: Hi Zeeshan, So if you want to use same controller then why you need different names ? If controller and its behavior is same for all template urls then you may just use one controller for all.

Comment: Hi Rupesh, i have different names in different templateUrl as ng-controller='names'

Comment: my main purpose is only make coder js code shorter nothing else

Comment: @Zeeshan, Hi, If I understood your requirement you are only writing the configuration where you write url name and controller name then use the same solution that I gave you can still use a class that has url and controller name in it. Use the same class to get the controller name based on the URL. Or are you are saying you do not have control over configuration and it comes from someone else and you have to put dynamically the controller name from URL into your own file ? Please elaborate !